# Observing properties of a class(ViewModel) from another class

Tags: swift, swiftui

Usually, in a SecondView, to listen to the properties from a FirstViewModel initialized in FirstView, the @StateObject ViewModel object is passes to the SecondView and initialized as @ObservedObject. But if I want to use the data from FirstViewModel in the SecondViewModel, I have to pass data from the view to the viewModel. So I tested out passing the FirstViewModel to the SecondView, then to the SecondViewModel on initialisation and getting access to the data from the FirstViewModel directly from the SecondViewModel. This way I make calling functions simple and leaving the view struct for view only. I was successful.

```
class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var isGreen = false
}
```

```
struct FirstView: View
{
    @StateObject var firstVM = FirstViewModel()

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationStack
        {
            Form
            {
                Toggle("First View", isOn: $firstVM.isGreen)
                
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView(firstVM: firstVM)
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to second View")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var firstVM: FirstViewModel

    init(firstVM: FirstViewModel)
    {
        self.firstVM = firstVM
    }

}
```

```
struct SecondView: View
{
    @StateObject var secondVM: SecondViewModel

//  @ObservedObject var firstVM: FirstViewModel

    init(firstVM: FirstViewModel) {
        _secondVM = StateObject(wrappedValue: SecondViewModel(firstVM: firstVM))

//  self.firstVM = firstVM
    }

    var body: some View
    {
        Form
        {
            Section
            {
                Button("Button")
                {
                    secondVM.firstVM.isGreen.toggle()
                }
                
                Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $secondVM.firstVM.isGreen)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 4)
                    .foregroundColor(secondVM.firstVM.isGreen ? .green : .red)
            } header: {
                Text("Published Property")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Setup:

- FirstViewModel contains simply boolean Published property "isGreen" & initialized in FirstView
- SecondViewModel contains Published property of type "FirstViewModel" which is assigned on initialization
- SecondView takes a property of type "FirstViewModel" on initialization to pass it to the SecondViewModel
- In SecondView, "isGreen" property is accessed exclusively from the SecondViewModel
- "@ObservedObject var firstVM: FirstViewModel" in SecondView is commented out and uncommented to observe behavior.

My Observations are as follows:

- Both the button and the toggle publish changes to the "isGreen" property, this is true because when SecondView is dismissed, FirstView's Toggle changes accordingly.
- However in observing changes, the Rectangle in the SecondView does not change color when using the Button, but does when using Toggle (Binding property)
- If I uncomment "@ObservedObject var firstVM: FirstViewModel" and "self.firstVM = firstVM" in SecondView, using the button now also publish changes to the SecondView even thought I am not using the instance "@ObservedObject var firstVM: FirstViewModel" itself. Its mere existence provided the SecondViewModel class the ability to observe changes from the FirstViewModel through its "@Published var firstVM: FirstViewModel" property

Additional Note:

In SecondViewModel, Changing

> @Published var firstVM: FirstViewModel

To

> let firstVM: FirstViewModel

I observe the same behavior described in point #3, only difference is that I cannot use the Toggle because it is a Binding property.

My Question is for point #3, how does the existence of the ObservedObject in SecondView allow SecondViewModel to listen new changes from the FirstViewModel, also how does switching to "let firstVM: FirstViewModel" also works? And why does that not apply when binding "isGreen" to the toggle, it's like the whole view gets bind to it too. Might this be related to the fact that class objects are stored in a common heap so instances get merged together?

Comment: ViewModels should never speak to each other or even know about each other.Move any shared data down to a manager

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct already is a View model so just just remove your objects and learn body, state and binding